# Retrieving bean in AspectJ class using Spring

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I am using aspectJ class for Exception Handling aspect in Spring.
i need to read values from properties files which is defined in spring bean.
Presently I am reading property file using the context.
is there any other option.
earlier while i was using spring aop ,proxy object automatically read the properties file without accessing through the context.

Spring Config File

```
<bean id="applicationProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:/resources/config/application.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

public Properties exceptionProp = null;
```

ExceptionHandlingAspect Class(i have to use context for reading propeties here)

```
 public class ExceptionHamdlingAspect{

public void setExceptionProp(Properties exceptionProp) {
    this.exceptionProp=exceptionProp;
}

 @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "ExceptionHandlingAspect()", throwing = "ex")
public void logAfterThrowingException(final JoinPoint currentJp,
        Throwable ex) throws Exception {

ApplicationContext ctx = AppContext.getApplicationContext();
this.exceptionProp=(Properties) ctx.getBean("applicationProperties");   


PropertyReader.getValueForProperty(ex.getClass().getSimpleName(),exceptionProp);
System.out.println("error values :"+errorString[0]+ errorString[1]);


}

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wire up your aspect using the static `aspectOf` factory method (you can't see that method, it is added by the aspectj compiler)

```
<bean class="com.YourAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
    <property name="exceptionProp"
              value="classpath:path/to/propfile.properties" />
</bean>
```

Reference:

- [`aspectOf()` and `hasAspect()`
  methods](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspectof.html)
- [Spring Dependency Injecting an
  annotated Aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1343952/342852)

Comment: i have added a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531722/not-able-to-use-request-scope-in-the-spring-config-file).please go throught it